# jQuery Collision Plugin for game character / div

Tags: jquery, collision

I'm aware there are a couple question similar but unfortunately they haven't quite been the answer to my problem... as far as I can tell.

Over the past couple nights whenever I've had some free time, I've been fiddling with creating a little type of game, which you can see a snippet/example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/8NW2K/) (WASD to move - Note: It's not cross browser compatible yet)

I'm using a plugin called [jQuery Collision](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-collision), it in theory does exactly what I would want it to do, but the examples given are done with draggable objects with the mouse and I'm having a few troubles adding it into my experiment.

I've tried adding this to my 'W' key in the attempt to say when the player collides with the obstacle, the obstacle should be removed.

```
    if ($("#player").collision("#obstacle")) {
        $("#obstacle").remove();
    }
```

Currently the obstacle is being removed but some times unexpectedly, if you place the player underneath the obstacle and press W (up) the box is removed, even though the player and obstacle haven't collided yet.

I've also tried other ways that I've seen in demo's which I also couldn't get working:

```
    var collided = $("#player").collision("#obstacle");

    if (collided.length > 0) {
        $("#obstacle").remove()
    }
```

Could anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE**

I'm aware there are plugins out there like gameQuery, so please don't recommend I just use that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin made to handle dragging:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/

The original suffers from the fact that as you drag around, the current position of the div isn't updated yet until you let go. It was meant to be a static collision checker. If you look carefully at the examples:

http://eruciform.com/jquerycollision/

...you'll see that, as you drag, the "overlap" is one frame behind. In order to not make assumptions about what the intended use of the module is (i.e. dragging), I left it as using whatever coordinates jQuery thinks the div is at. And that's why I created the dragging addition plugin. It has a lot of other bells and whistles, too, like "collision avoidance" during dragging.